# Repaint() not repainting images

Tags: java, paint, repaint

I'm making a pong game in Java to play around with the language and was wondering why my repaint method is not repainting the images on screen. Essentially what I want is when the ball hits either side of the screen to initiate a player has scored, I want to repaint everything in its starting place to emulate a reset. I've tried putting repaint all over the place, but it either leads to the everything locking up or the game continuing on as if nothing happened.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private Timer timer;
    private PlayerOne paddle;
    private PlayerTwo paddle2;
    private Ball ball;
    private boolean ingame = true;
    int playeronescore = 0;
    int playertwoscore = 0;

    public Board()
    {

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        paddle = new PlayerOne();
        paddle2 = new PlayerTwo();
        ball = new Ball();

        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();
    }

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if(ingame)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(paddle2.getImage(), paddle2.getX(), paddle2.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        restartGame();
        repaint();
    } 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    paddle.move();
    paddle2.move();
    ball.move();
    checkCollision();
    repaint();
}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        paddle.keyPressed(e);
        paddle2.keyPressed(e);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        paddle.keyReleased(e);
        paddle2.keyReleased(e);
    }
}
public void restartGame()//resetting the paddles and ball into their initial positions
{
    paddle.setX(0);
    paddle.setY(60);
    paddle2.setX(280);
    paddle2.setY(60);
    ball.setX(140);
    ball.setY(60);

}
public void checkCollision()
{
    Rectangle r1 = paddle.getBounds();
    Rectangle r2 = paddle2.getBounds();
    Rectangle r3 = ball.getBounds();

    if(ball.getX() == 0)
    {
        playeronescore++;
        ingame = false;
    }

    if(ball.getX() == 280)
    {
        playertwoscore++;
        ingame = false;
    }

    if(r3.intersects(r1))
    {
        int paddleLPos = (int)paddle.getBounds().getMinX();
        int ballLPos = (int)ball.getBounds().getMinX();

        int first = paddleLPos + 8;
        int second = paddleLPos + 16;
        int third = paddleLPos + 24;
        int fourth = paddleLPos + 32;

        if (ballLPos < first) {
            ball.setXDir(-1);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }

        if (ballLPos >= first && ballLPos < second) {
            ball.setXDir(-1);
            ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
        }

        if (ballLPos >= second && ballLPos < third) {
            ball.setXDir(0);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }

        if (ballLPos >= third && ballLPos < fourth) {
            ball.setXDir(1);
            ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
        }

        if (ballLPos > fourth) {
            ball.setXDir(1);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }           
    }
    else if(r3.intersects(r2))
    {
        int paddleLPos = (int)paddle2.getBounds().getMinX();
        int ballLPos = (int)ball.getBounds().getMinX();

        int first = paddleLPos + 8;
        int second = paddleLPos + 16;
        int third = paddleLPos + 24;
        int fourth = paddleLPos + 32;

        if (ballLPos < first) {
            ball.setXDir(-1);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }

        if (ballLPos >= first && ballLPos < second) {
            ball.setXDir(-1);
            ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
        }

        if (ballLPos >= second && ballLPos < third) {
            ball.setXDir(0);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }

        if (ballLPos >= third && ballLPos < fourth) {
            ball.setXDir(1);
            ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
        }

        if (ballLPos > fourth) {
            ball.setXDir(1);
            ball.setYDir(-1);
        }           
    }
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The painting method should not be used to change the properties of your components. That is the restartGame() method should not be part of the painting. When the game is finished, you reset the properties of your components and then invoke repaint(). There is no need for your Boolean indicator in the paint() method. Also, Custom Painting should be done in the paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you have a few issues here.

First you should override `paintComponents` not `paint`.

Second, `repaint()` calls `paint`.  So the reason your game is locking is that you're effectively forcing it into a never ending loop.  `paint` is called, which calls `repaint` which calls `paint` which etc etc etc.

Finally, as carmickr said in a comment, you shouldn't be changing component properties in the `paint` method.

So.  Putting all that together, I'd suggest you relook at the `actionPerformed` logic.  As you say you're learning I'm a bit loathe to just hand you a pile of code, but a few hints:

You determine in `checkCollision` whether a point has been scored.  What about returning something from that method to your `actionPerformed` method - if a point has been scored then do this, if not then do that.  At the end of that you'll need to call `paintComponent` so you'll need some flag - a Boolean variable probably - telling `paintComponent` whether to draw the updated positions of the bats or the initial position at the least, carmickr's suggestion of resetting the positions and just having one route through `paintComponent` is the better one though.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
if(ingame)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(paddle2.getImage(), paddle2.getX(), paddle2.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
else
{
    restartGame();
    repaint();
} 

}
```

to

```
 public void paint(Graphics g)
{
if(ingame)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(paddle2.getImage(), paddle2.getX(), paddle2.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
else
{
    restartGame();

} 
  repaint();
}
```

This will essentially repaint the screen as the entire game is running, instaed of by logic as you had it.

Hope this helps!